# Find the value of Given function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let, $f(z)$  be  analytics   in $|z| \le 1$ and $|f(z) |\le  1$ with $f(0) = \frac{1 +i}{\sqrt 2}$ . Then find the  value of $f(i) -f(1)$

I Thinks  it will be  $0$  by Liouville theorem.

Is Its correct ??

Comment: Since Liouville's theorem is for **entire** functions, I don't see how you plan to apply it here.

Comment: Okkkss sir @jose Carlos santos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** $|f(0)|=1$. Use Maximum Modulus Theorem, which states that *"A non constant analytic function in a domain $D$ attains maximum value on it's boundary $\partial D$.*

Comment: Then answer will be 0 na??

Comment: @santosh Yeah !